# Unable to call JAX-WS client deployed on JBoss 7.1.1

Tags: jboss, jax-ws, jbossws

I have a generated jax-ws web service client that runs fine when I run it as a java standalone project. However if I add it to a web application (war) deployed on JBoss 7.1.1 and call the web service it throws the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ctc/wstx/io/DefaultInputResolver
at com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory.createSR(WstxInputFactory.java:628)
at com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(WstxInputFactory.java:324)
at __redirected.__XMLInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(__XMLInputFactory.java:139) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.createXMLStreamReader(StaxUtils.java:1176)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.StaxInInterceptor.handleMessage(StaxInInterceptor.java:104)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:795)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1626)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1493)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1401)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:648)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:531)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:461)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:364)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:317)
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:88)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:134)
at $Proxy189.getcodelists(Unknown Source)
```

Idea what I may be missing?

Comment: What library are you using for you jax-ws client?  JBoss use cxf, so if you provide you own cxf jars, there may be some class loading issues.  Can you try using the JBoss as provided jax-ws libs?

Comment: My jax-ws client has only jax-ws api classes and no implementation dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, the App server is unable to find the said class file. Is it possible in your standalone app your classpath has the library but JBoss AS 7 is unable to find it.

If you can isolate where this library is, you can either bundle it with your WAR file or create a [jboss_module](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODULES/Introduction?focusedCommentId=12648529#comment-12648529) to satisfy the dependency.

Good luck!

Comment: Looks like a StAX library problem.